# How can I interpret the substantive size of a log likelihood or increase in log likelihood

Tags: likelihood, r-squared, likelihood-ratio

If I run a linear regression and get an R-squared, it has a substantive interpretation: this is how much of the variance in the sample the model explained. If I add a term and see an increase in R-squared, that also has a substantive interpretation. An increase from R-squared from 0.1 to 0.5 is substantively important. An increase from 0.1 to 0.105 probably isn't, even if it is highly significant.

Many models don't have a natural R-squared, so instead we look at the log likelihood. Is there a natural way to understand the "size" of a log likelihood? When we compare two log likelihoods, we might do a likelihood ratio test. That tests whether one model is significantly better than the other. But is there a way to understand the substantive importance of the improvement, as there is for the R-squared?

I thought that log-likelihood divided by N might work, since it gives the "per-person" probability of the data given the model. But I'm not sure about this.

Comment: pseudo r-squared? https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/

Comment: Indeed it looks as if Cox and Snell, and Nagelkerke, are following my rough idea. They use 2/N not 1/N and take roots of likelihoods instead of dividing log likelihoods. Could you give an example of how to interpret, e.g. a certain improvement in one of these statistics?